# How to load Log4j2 configuration file from resource

Tags: java, log4j2

I would like to know how to load the configuration file for Log4j from a resource that is embedded in my application?

That is, I do not have a file on the computer itself, the file is embedded in my application, and I would like to load it.

Following is the code I used:

```
ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/in/gunbound/prelauncher/server/log4j2/log4j2.xml"));
ConfigurationFactory factory = (ConfigurationFactory) XMLConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(source);
ConfigurationFactory.setConfigurationFactory(factory);
```

But the result was this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.XMLConfiguration cannot be cast
>   to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory at
>   in.gunbound.prelauncher.server.Main.main(Main.java:62)

I do not want to leave the settings file visible to the user, so I am with this problem, you know?

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.html#getConfiguration%28org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.ConfigurationSource%29) for reference.

The return type for `XMLConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(source);` is `Configuration` not `ConfigurationFactory`.

Comment: Exactly. I tried to cast this type to ConfigurationFactory but not getting success. Could you help me reach the goal? Basically, the thing is, I have a configuration file in XML Log4j2, but it is embedded in my application as a resource, and I want to load the settings from it, not to let the configuration file visible to the user, understand?

Comment: where is log4j.xml reside ? in a jar files?

Comment: I created a package in my application and imported the XML file, ie it will be embedded in the JAR, when I generate it, you know?

I would carry it that way, because I do not want the settings file is visible to users.